# Scala logging : Log4cats ambigious implicits

Tags: scala, logging, implicit, scala-cats, ambiguity

I'm a newbie, and I want to test log4cats library for managing scala logging. I can't seem to grasp the intuition behind, I tried testing the example on the documentation but I can't seem to get it working.

Here is what I have tried :

```
import io.chrisdavenport.log4cats.Logger
import io.chrisdavenport.log4cats.slf4j.Slf4jLogger
import cats.effect.{ExitCode, IO, IOApp, Sync}
import cats.implicits._

object Thing extends IOApp {

  // Impure But What 90% of Folks I know do with log4s
  implicit def unsafeLogger[F[_]: Sync] = Slf4jLogger.getLogger[F]

  // Arbitrary Local Function Declaration
  def doSomething[F[_]: Sync]: F[Unit] =
    Logger[F].info("Logging Start Something") *>
      Sync[F].delay(println("I could be doing anything")).attempt.flatMap {
        case Left(e)  => Logger[F].error(e)("Something Went Wrong")
        case Right(_) => Sync[F].pure(())
      }

  override def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] = {
    //implicitly[Sync[IO]]
    doSomething
    IO(ExitCode.Success)
  }
}
```

I'm getting this error: diverging implicit expansion for type cats.effect.Sync[F]

Comment: You probably want to do this `doSomenthing[IO].as(ExitCode.Success)` which shows you aren't familiar with how `IO` works, I would suggest first getting familiar with that.